# Finding 3 hourly averages of the data

Tags: matlab

In the below code, each y is of 8 min duration. Once I generate the Powerr matrix I have what I Need but How do i do 3 hour averages? Should i do within the for loop or once I generate the Powerr matrix can i still be able to find out the 3 hourly averages of my data? thanks in advance.

```
fid = fopen([directory '001/listing.txt'],'r');
   tline = fgetl(fid);
       ii = 0;
   while (tline ~= -1)
            if (length(tline) == 0)  
               continue
            end
            ii = ii + 1;
            file_names(ii,:)=tline;  % create file names in matlab data worksapace
            year(ii) = str2num(tline(11:14));
            month(ii) = str2num(tline(15:16));
            day(ii) = str2num(tline(17:18));
            hour(ii) = str2num(tline(20:21));
            min(ii) = str2num(tline(22:23));
            sec(ii) = str2num(tline(24:25));
            tline = fgetl(fid);
   end   
   fclose(fid);
   timestamp = datenum(year,month,day,hour,min,sec);




%--------window applied is Hanning window--------                                              
   nfft = 4096;                              % |
    hanning_window = hanning(nfft); % |
%-------------------------------------------------
    timestamp = datenum(year,month,day,hour,min,sec);


tic
profile on
warning('off','MATLAB:audiovideo:wavread:functionToBeRemoved');
    neglect_the_first_few= 5;
    lastfile = 20;
    Powerr = zeros(2049,20);
%     fr = zeros(2049,1);
   count =[];
    parfor count = neglect_the_first_few + 1 :lastfile
    warning('off','MATLAB:audiovideo:wavread:functionToBeRemoved');

                y= [];
%             for inputfile = infiles'
                fn = [directory '/001/' file_names(count,:)];

                 [y,fs,nbits] = wavread(fn,'native');   
                disp(['sampling freq is ',num2str(fs),' hz. length of y is ',num2str(size(y)),'filenumber is ',num2str(count)])

%             end

            y = y- mean(y);
             Y = double(y).*(1.49365435131571e-07);%CONVERSION - volts per bit for 24bit channel
%             clear y;

             nooverlap =[];%number of overlapped segments set to zero on Nov20th 2017
            [Poww,fr] = pwelch(Y,hanning_window,nooverlap,nfft,fs);%no overlap taken into account%



            Powerr(:,count) = Poww;
            freq(:,count)= fr;

    end
```

Comment: It is hard to understand. What do you want to average?

Comment: I wish to do 3hour averages instead of the current 8min average..the current code is taking in each file which is of 8min duration

Comment: So You want to treat not each file separately, but join several files together. The problem is 3h=180min, 180 min/8 min=22.5, so You could not have 3h from integer number of files. And, second do you want to concatenate  `fn` or `y`? Which dimention has this variable? Shuld be vertical or horizontal concat. performed?

Comment: Yes i cannot exactly have 3hr!

Comment: In my code the timestamp is the variable that has timeinformation..Im thinking I  can do something like minstamp = start : timestep: time end and set my timestep as the equivalent minutes and find out the indices in my Power that correspond to the 3hr sets and then do mean of the Power at those indices but I'm not 100% sure if that will work..any comments on that are welcome

Comment: can someone please help me